# How can I add post-flavoring to beer?

Tags: taste, flavor, ingredients

I'm having a party and I want to add flavors to my already-brewed beer. How can I do that and have it mix?

Answer (score 4):

Any time you mix things into beer you'll lose some carbonation. Any powder would nucleate bubbles very quickly, so the flavoring should be in liquid form. The liquid should be as similar to beer possible: cold, equally carbonated, and not too much alcohol if it can be avoided. Stir gently in a cold glass and serve right away.

Or, if you are brewing the beer yourself just add it at kegging or bottling time.

Comment: I would add an additional option: Dogfish Head's [Randall the Enamel Animal](http://www.dogfish.com/company/tangents/randall-the-enamel-animal.htm) and its cousin: [Randall Jr](http://www.dogfish.com/store/other-accessories/randall-jr.htm) which are infusion products for use with tap and bottle beer, respectively, that let you steep flavorings and aromatics in the beer as you serve them.  Because of the pressure Randall flavors pretty quickly but Randall Jr needs to sit for a bit, but they both attempt to save some carbonation.

Answer (score 1):

There are products called Randalizers that can allow you to infuse flavors into beer as it's served. Provided that the beer is 1) on draft, and 2) the flavoring is a solid (hops, peppercorns, citrus peel, etc). An expensive option is the [Blichman Hoprocket](http://www.northernbrewer.com/shop/blichmann-hoprocket.html). Another option I've seen, but I'm not sure how to construct it, was an inline water filter that had been modified. That modified filter also required significantly more CO2 to maintain pressure, I don't think that was true of the purpose built devices.

These work well for fresh flavors, but would serve poorly if you were looking for anything else. I've had beers run through a couple different combinations of herbs, fruit, veggies, and hops, and it was always interesting and exciting. Even if it wasn't always that good.